# Display R-T-L Language (Hebrew) Reversed

Tags: blackberry, lwuit, nokia, right-to-left

I have xml file with results.

In this file i have an element that consists of a string phone number like this: `xxxxx 053 333333333`, but it's displayed in the application like `xxxxx 333333333 053`.

Why does this happen? It seems that when parsing, the parser relates this sentence like it is write in english and not hebrew.

This happens in Nokia and BlackBerry. I'm using lwuit.

My conclusion is that it occurs because of lwuit (?)

Comment: You have to show us the code you're using for us to be helpful.

Comment: great question! let me know if you get what you need

Answer (score 2):

I also had some problems with bidirectional text rendering. A good explanation is here: http://www.iamcal.com/understanding-bidirectional-text/

My solution was to use explicit markers LRE, RLE and PDF when I know that a sentence is written in a particular language.

Comment: Thanks, but this only in html. how i can do it with XML files?

Comment: It's not easy to answer without seeing any code. If you are displaying a string on the screen, and you know it's right-to-left, then instead of: setText(string) you could try setText("\u202B" + string + "\u202C")